# How to handle NaNs in pandas dataframe integer column to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, pandas, null, integer, nan

I have a pandas dataframe with a "year" column. However some rows have a np.NaN value due to an outer merge. The data type of the column in pandas is therefore converted to float64 instead of integer (integer cannot store NaNs?). Next, I want to store the dataframe on a postGreSQL database. For this I use:

```
df.to_sql()
```

Everything works fine but my postGreSQL column is now type "double precision" and the np.NaN values are now [null]. This all makes sense since the input column type was float64 and not integer type.

I was wondering if there is a way to store the results in an integer type column with [nans].

Example [Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rutgerhofste/fd0c5e30b9e66693c4ea50564b342c4f)

Result of Ami's answer:

[image]

Comment: Try `df.astype(object).to_sql()` and try again?

Comment: @coldspeed that changes the table schema - not sure it's warranted.

Comment: @AmiTavory If the schema is already defined, then I don't think so. By the way, fillna will not downcast... :)

Comment: @coldspeed Ooh, excellent point - missed that. Will update. thanks!

Comment: @coldspeed, the result is still double precision in postgreSQL. I've added a notebook to my question to check if my implememtation is wrong.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138888/convert-pandas-column-containing-floats-and-nan-values-from-float64-to-nullabl/63381205#63381205

Answer (score 5):

> (integer cannot store NaNs?)

No, they cannot. If you look at the [postgresql numeric documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html), you can see that the number of bytes, and ranges, are completely specified, and integers cannot store this.

A common solution in this case is to decide, by convention, that some number is logically a nan. In your case, if it is year, you might choose a negative value (or just -1) as that. Before writing, you could use

```
df.year = df.year.fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

Alternatively, you can define another column as `year_is_none`.

Alternatively, you can store them as floats.

These solutions range from most efficient, to least efficient in terms of memory.

Comment: Alternatively, if you use `NUMERIC` data type, you can store `Infinity`, `-Infinity` as well as `NaN` values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it;

```
df.year = df.year.fillna(-1) OR 0
```