# Convert pandas column (containing floats and NaN values) from float64 to nullable int8

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, nan

I have a large dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   2.2 6.0 0.0
1   3.3 7.0 NaN
2   4.4 NaN 3.0
3   5.5 9.0 NaN
```

Columns b and c contain float values that are either postive, natural numbers or NaN. However, they are stored as float64, which is a problem, since (without going into further detail) this dataframe is the input of a pipeline that requires these to be integers, so and I want to store them as such. The output should look like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   2.2 6   0
1   3.3 7   NaN
2   4.4 NaN 3
3   5.5 9   NaN
```

I read in the pandas documentation that nullable integers are only supported in the pandas datatype "Int8" (note: this is different from np.int8), so naturally, I attempted this:

`df = df.astype({'b':pd.Int8Dtype(), 'c':pd.Int8Dtype()})`

This works when I run it in my Jupyter notebook, but when I integrate it within a larger function, I get this error:

`TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int8`

I understand why I get the error, since x == int(x), will be False for NaN values, so the program thinks this conversion is unsafe, even though all values are either NaN or natural number. So next, I tried:

`'df = df.astype({'b':pd.Int8Dtype(), 'c':pd.Int8Dtype()}, errors='ignore')`

I figured that this would get rid of the 'unsafe conversion' problem, since I am 100% sure all float64 values are natural numbers. However, when I use this line, all of my numbers are still stored as floats! Infuriating!

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: you can't have a column with `NaN` be stored as an integer type. you will have to replace the `NaN` values or deal with it upstream

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exactly the same issue which led me to this page. I do not have a genuinely good solution for this issue and am seeking for one myself... but I did find a workaround. Before going into that I would like to answer to the comment posted on the original question that: allowing to have `NA` or even `None` values assigned to series of such 'simple' types as `int8` is the whole point of trying to make these dtype conversions. It is possible to perform the typical operations such as `isna()` (and so on) on series of these dtypes (see pd.Int**X**Dtype() where '**X**' stands for the number of bits). The advantage I explore by using these dtypes is on memory footprint, eg:

```
In[56]: test_df = pd.Series(np.zeros(1_000_000), dtype=np.float64)

In[57]: test_df.memory_usage()
Out[57]: 8000128

In[58]: test_df = pd.Series(np.zeros(1_000_000), dtype=pd.Int8Dtype())

In[59]: test_df.memory_usage()
Out[59]: 2000128

In[60]: test_df.iloc[:500_000] = None

In[61]: test_df.memory_usage()
Out[61]: 2000128

In[62]: test_df.isna().sum()
Out[62]: 500000
```

So you get the best of both worlds.

Now the workarround:

```
In[33]: my_df
Out[33]: 
     a    s      d
0    0 -500 -1.000
1    1 -499 -0.998
2    2 -498 -0.996
3    3 -497 -0.994
4    4 -496 -0.992

In[34]: my_df.dtypes
Out[34]: 
a      int64
s      int64
d    float64
dtype: object

In[35]: df_converted_to_int_first = my_df.astype(
   ...:     dtype={
   ...:         'a': np.int8,
   ...:         's': np.int16,
   ...:         'd': np.float16,
   ...:     },
   ...: )

In[36]: df_converted_to_int_first
Out[36]: 
     a    s         d
0    0 -500 -1.000000
1    1 -499 -0.998047
2    2 -498 -0.996094
3    3 -497 -0.994141
4    4 -496 -0.992188

In[37]: df_converted_to_int_first.dtypes
Out[37]: 
a       int8
s      int16
d    float16
dtype: object

In[38]: df_converted_to_special_int_after = df_converted_to_int_first.astype(
   ...:     dtype={
   ...:         'a': pd.Int8Dtype(),
   ...:         's': pd.Int16Dtype(),
   ...:     }
   ...: )

In[39]: df_converted_to_special_int_after.dtypes
Out[39]: 
a       Int8
s      Int16
d    float16
dtype: object

In[40]: df_converted_to_special_int_after.a.iloc[3] = None

In[41]: df_converted_to_special_int_after
Out[41]: 
       a     s         d
0      0  -500 -1.000000
1      1  -499 -0.998047
2      2  -498 -0.996094
3   <NA>  -497 -0.994141
4      4  -496 -0.992188
```

This is still not an acceptable solution in my opinion... but as mentioned above ir constitutes a workaround which is asked in the original question.

**EDIT**
Some test that was missing, from np.float64 to pd.Int8Dtype():

```
In[67]: my_df.astype(
   ...:     dtype={
   ...:         'a': np.int8,
   ...:         's': np.int16,
   ...:         'd': np.int16,
   ...:     },
   ...: ).astype(    
   ...:     dtype={
   ...:         'a': np.int8,
   ...:         's': np.int16,
   ...:         'd': pd.Int8Dtype(),
   ...:     },
   ...: ).dtypes

Out[67]: 
a     int8
s    int16
d     Int8
dtype: object
```