# How can I convert an "Object" variable with NaN into an "Int" variable In Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

In a dataframe, I want to make a simple addition between columns (these are dummy variables), but as they are dtype: "O", my final output its like:

```
data_final.eval('violencia = D104 + D106 + D107 + D108')
data_final['violencia'].value_counts()

0000    14362
        14112
0100     1866
1100     1611
1000     1425
1110      901
1111      679
0110      337
1101      324
0101       74
1001       66
0001       57
0111       52
0010       22
1010       16
0011        3
1011        2
Name: violencia, dtype: int64
```

I've tried the following coding:

```
data_final['D104'] = data_final['D104'].astype(float)
data_final['D104'] = data_final['D104'].astype('Int64')
data_final['D104'] = data_final['D104'].fillna().astype('Int64')
```

And

```
data_final['D107'] = pd.to_numeric(data_final['D107'], errors='coerce').astype('int32')
```

They all drop the same error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a list of values of `data_final['D107']`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138888/14094460) answer your question?

Comment: I was able to solve it by using 
````
data_final['D104'] = data_final['D104'].replace(' ', np.nan)
data_final['D104'] = pd.to_numeric(data_final['D104'], errors='coerce')
data_final['D104'] = data_final['D104'].astype('Int64')

The issue was that there were " " observations, so first I converted them into NaN

Comment: Thak you so much!